# Copiar campos de um formulário e colar em outro formulário de sites diferentes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extensão, applet

estou desenvolvendo um sistema particular, utilizando PHP, JQUERY, MYSQL, e preciso meio que automatizar uma rotina:

Tenho um formulário de cadastro no meu sistema web e preciso de alguma ferramenta ou app do google chrome que me permita copiar todos esses campos do meu formulário e colar num outro formulário de um outro site que não me pertence.

O que acontece é que eu tenho o meu sistema onde alimento os dados cadastrais de um determinado cliente e tem um outro sistema que não me pertence onde preciso por questões administrativas preencher os mesmos dados.

Infelizmente esse sistema de terceiros não possui nenhum ferramenta de interação onde eu pudesse importar algum arquivo para carregamento. Então estou tentando desenvolver ou utilizar alguma ferramenta que me permita copiar e colar de forma mais rápida.

Fico grato.

Comment: O Selenium é uma ferrameta de automação para testes. Talvez você consiga automatizar esse processo com ele. Mas isso não significa transformar esse procedimento em um sistema, caso seja a sua necessidade. Um link sobre a ferramenta: https://www.devmedia.com.br/testes-automatizados-com-o-framework-selenium/32955

Comment: Obrigado @JoaoPaulo, vou dar uma lida e verificar se atende minha necessidade.

Comment: Você precisa mesmo preencher esse outro formulário? Enviar um POST direto da sua aplicação, não funcionaria?

Comment: @JúlioNeto meu sistema web não tem qualquer integração com esse outro site. O que eu precisa é de alguma ferramenta ou sabe-se lá o que, que me permita copias as informações dos campos do form do meu sistema e me permita colar nos campos do form desse outro site automaticamente. O submit desse outro site eu faria manualmente. Só estou tentando achar uma forma de não precisar digitar as mesmas coisas nos dois sistemas. Como um desses sistemas não é meu não tenho como fazer nenhum integração interna. por isso pensei em algum applet ou algo do tipo que me permitisse copiar e colar vários "inputs"

Answer (score -1):

Isso é bem simples por incrível que pareça
Faz o seguinte teste, vai no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Agora vai por esse endereço

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?q=Churrasco

Vai reparar nisso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Chrome tratou o atributo `name` do `input` de pesquisa que se chama `q`
e colocou o valor que mandei por URL.

Caso queira dar o submit automaticamente é simples também, vai no site que quer e poem isso na URL

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('This is an XSS Vulnerability')
</script>
```

Se der certo você pode usar o .Trigger ou .submit caso tiver Jquery no site.